# How to restrict AzureAD application to single location

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, office365, sharepoint-online

We have application on own server that should work with SharePoint Online. To access SP Online we need to have app token/secret - that's fine.

I wonder if there's possibility to restrict access via this token to some location for additional security. Let's say we have some machine with static IP that should connect to SP Online and machines with different IPs should not be able to connect even if they have right token/secret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [**Azure AD Conditional Access Policies**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/overview).

The specific scenario you describe here will qualify for a condition based on Network Location. See here:

[image]

You just need to make use of location condition by defining Named Locations:

[image]

[image]

**NOTE**: This feature does require an Azure AD Premium License. You can compare different editions [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/pricing/details/active-directory/)